# is there a way to bind html file with my GWT widgets

Tags: gwt

I have this HTML file for a simple Login page

```
   <g:HTMLPanel>
 <div class="login">
    <div class="heading">
        <h2>Sign in</h2>
        <form action="#">
       <g:Label ui:field="lblError" styleName="errorFields"></g:Label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username or email" ui:field="txtUserName"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ui:field="txtPassword"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="float" ui:field="btnSubmit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now is there a way I can bind this in my GWT .
I put this Html in my uibinder.xml file...
But then it says

```
   Type mismatch: cannot convert from InputElement to TextBox
```

But if i change the input to GWT textbox , whole styling disturbs.
I want to have the exact same styling/effects of this html file in my GWT.

Please advice.

Comment: Why don't you use <g:TextBox> instead?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the error you receive just means that in your java file (for this uiBinder) you've mapped txtUserName wrong;
yours is like:

```
@UiField
TextBox txtUserName;
```

Change it to

```
@UiField
InputElement txtUserName
```

But be aware - InputElement will have really small amount of functions to work with. You can "convert" this line

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ui:field="txtUserName"/>
```

to

```
<g:TextBox setStyleName="form-control" ui:field="txtUserName">
```

You can then set the placeholder in your java file (in the constructor after the uiBinder call):
txtUserName.setAttribute("placeholder", "Username or email");

And to be sure your style is not overriden by GWT default theme - please check your ...gwt.xml file does not contain not commented lines like:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: yes it is possible to bind to existing input elements. I used it myself for creating a login form, which should be able to allow autofill of username/password. *(As far as I remember that was only possible in some browsers if the input elements were already existing during page load contained in HTML not added by GWT).*

You can create a textbox that binds to the existing input element using [`TextBox.wrap(element)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)) and [`PasswordTextBox.wrap(element)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PasswordTextBox.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)) like that:

```
Element elemUsername = DOM.getElementById("login_username");
Element elemPassword = DOM.getElementById("login_password");
txtUserName = TextBox.wrap(elemUsername);
txtPassword = PasswordTextBox.wrap(elemPassword);
```

As a consequence, you would have to remove the `ui:field` tags in your HTML file.

And either you change the the `@UiField` annotation to `@UiField(provided = true)` for these textboxes in your java file and wrap the elements in the constructor of the form - or you have to remove this annotation completely and bind events manually (by code) if you need them.